# How to skip a string when reading a file line by line

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I have managed to skip the name section when reading values from a file with name and value pairs. But is there another way to skip the name section without declaring a dummy string to store the skipped data?

Example text file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/94l1w.png

```
void loadConfigFile()
{
    ifstream file(folder + "config.txt");

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file >> skip;

        file >> screenMode;
        if (screenMode == "on")
            notFullScreen = 0;
        else if (screenMode == "off")
            notFullScreen = 1;

        file >> skip;
        file >> playerXPosMS;

        file >> skip;
        file >> playerYPosMS;

        file >> skip;
        file >> playerGForce;
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::cin.ignore` to ignore input up to some specified delimiter (e.g., a new-line, to skip an entire line).

```
static const int max_line = 65536;

std::cin.ignore(max_line, '\n');
```

While many people recommend specifying a maximum of something like `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`, I do  not. If the user accidentally points the program at the wrong file, they shouldn't wait while it consumes an inordinate amount of data before being told something's wrong.

Two other points.

1. Don't use `while (!file.eof())`. It mostly leads to problems. For a case like this,  you really want to define a `struct` or `class` to hold your related values, define an `operator>>` for that class, then use `while (file>>player_object) ...`
2. The way you're reading right now really tries to read a "word" at a time, not a whole line. If you want to read a whole line, you probably want to use `std::getline`.

Comment: Can you show the ur first two other points? I have no idea to design while (file>>player_object). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user: [One Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10509958/179910) that's  similar to yours -- mostly reads lines of text, and includes skipping a line (though it uses `std::getline` to do so).